# How can I port a custom OS to EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to run a custom OS on EC2? I poked around and couldn't find an answer to how this might be done or if it could be done at all.

Answer (score 1):

What's your definition of a "custom OS"? You can use all sorts of prebuilt machine images (AMIs) for Windows Server and various Linux distros (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#os). You can modify these AMIs and save these modifications as custom AMIs, too.

Comment: That's true, but I want to run my own OS of my own making, not windows or linux.

Comment: Amazon EC2 relies on virtualisation so that's probably not the easiest thing to do. I think your best bet would be to move this question to Serverfault, or even better, the official AWS support forums. They're probably better placed to answer this question :) Technically, it should be possible to run your own OS as long as it runs on x86 architectures, I'd imagine...but I can also see why Amazon wouldn't want everyone to do that.